# ASCII text not symmetric in UITextView as which is save in SQLite

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, sqlite, uitextview

I have saved ASCII characters in SQLIte database and when I print in the console,
It is symmetric like this:
[image]

But when I am trying to print on the UITextView
I get this result : 
[image]

The UITextView's Text is Attributed I even tried keeping it plain ... But same result ... 
Where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution ... Just changed font to courier ... It should have a Monospaced font ...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font and reduced the font size to fit in the textview.